# How can convert png file for iphone to standard png file using java

Tags: java, iphone, image, png

You know, png file for iphone can't display using image reader on windows.
How can convert png file for iphone to standard png file using java?

Is there any open-source library to do this?

Any response will be much appreciated.

Comment: Iphone "PNG" actually is one of Apple's abomination http://goo.gl/DhLyP. It's propietary,  patents pending, it pretends to be a PNG (not only from extension but by signature) and it's obviously not. The name of the format is CgBI http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format
And you can't always recover the original PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Can Java read the 'png file for iphone'?  If so, it would be trivial to write it back out<sup>1</sup> to a PNG in a form that Windows can read.

If not you need to look into either [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html) or an [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/package-summary.html) that supports that flavor of PNG.

1. See [`ImageIO.write(RenderedImage,String,File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As leonbloy said, iOS-optimized PNGs are actually not PNGs at all, they are considered to be "CgBI" format:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format

I know this wasn't around when the question was first asked, but here's a Java converter implementation:
https://github.com/viphe/ipng-converter

Answer (score 0):

yes you can convert iPhone PNG file to standard file using Java. Please go thought below link for script.
https://github.com/CuelogicTech/Convert-iOS-Application-PNG-images